# How to access 'this.props.match.params' along with other props?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I have this code in my parent component:

```
<Route path='/champions/:id' render={(props) => <ChampionDetails {...props} match={this.handleMatch}/>}/>
```

where the match prop will be a function that retrieves data from the child component (ChampionDetails). A snippet of my ChampionDetails (child) component:

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';

    class ChampionDetails extends Component {
      state = {
        champId:this.props.match.params.id,
        champData:null,
        match:false
      }

      componentDidMount(){
        console.log('ChampionDet mounted')
        this.handleChampInfo();
        console.log(this.props.match)
      }

      componentDidUpdate(){
        console.log('ChampionDet updated')
      }


      handleChampInfo=()=>{
        let champData = [];
        let id = this.state.champId
        console.log(id)
        fetch('/api/getChampion?id='+id)
          .then(data=> { return data.json() })
          .then(json=> {
            console.log(json.data);
            champData.push(json.data);
            this.setState({
              champData:json.data,
              match:true
            })
            this.props.match(true)
            // this.props.history.push('/champions/'+id)
          })
          .catch(err=>{
            console.log(err)
          })
      }

      render(){
        return(
          <div>
            <p>{this.state.champId}</p>
            {this.state.champData===null ? null:<p>{this.state.champData.roles}</p>}
          </div>
        )
      }
    }

    export default ChampionDetails;
```

The problem here is that if I have the match={} in my parent's route, then this.props.match.params.id will become undefined. If I remove match={} then I can retrieve this.props.match.params.id

I would like to know if its possible to be able to pass other props while still have access to this.props.match.params.id in my case.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can pass `matchProps` as the props from the router, `this.props` for any props from the parent and then just avoid overwriting props - your `match` prop is overriding the props from the route:

```
<Route path='/champions/:id' render={(matchProps) =>
  <ChampionDetails
    {...matchProps}
    {...this.props}
    handleMatch={this.handleMatch}
  />
}/>
```

When you spread `{...props}` your `match` prop overrides react-router's `match`.

Answer (score 20):

If you're using `react-router` version `>=4`, you should be able to access the router params at any component inside the router via `withRouter` HOC. For instance:

```
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
...
export withRouter(ChampionDetails);
```

Answer (score 0):

Match prop is part of the `react-router-dom`, so by making another props called match you are overwriting it.

The simplest way: just rename the `match={this.handleMatch}/>}` to something else like
`matchHandler={this.handleMatch}/>}`

If using the name `match` is essential, destruct it as `const {matchHandler : match} = this.props`