# Passing data between Router Components in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a `react-router-dom` based application where I currently have two screens: one for the initial setup and a second one that needs some information from the first. That information is stored in constants in the Home page's code, and I would like to know if there is a method for sharing the variables between them, or maybe passing them into the second in some way. The code and tree below provide a basic run-down of how I have it set up.

Structure:

```
                         App
                          |
                        Routes
                          |
                    BrowserRouter
      ____________________|____________________
     |                                         |
   Route                                     Route
    Home ———— history.push("/in-game") ———> InGame
                      (+data)
```

Home code snippet:

```
const history = useHistory();
const toGame = () => history.push('/in-game');

const [colors, setColors] = useState();——————————
const [map, setMap] = useState();————————————————|—————————data I'd like to share with the InGame component
const [myColor, setMyColor] = useState();————————
```

Really hoping I can get a hand with this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use history object for this.

to change route from "home" to "ingame" with additional data to be passed into "ingame",

Home.js

```
const someEventHandler = event => {
       history.push({
           pathname: '/in-game',
           state: { map: map }
       });
    };
```

to access this in "InGame",

InGame.js

```
 const location = useLocation();

 console.log(location.state.map); //map value is available here
```

try above. for more on history, https://reactrouter.com/web/api/history refer these docs from react-router.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this out and see how it goes.

Comment: Worked like a charm after I figured it out. Thanks!

Comment: welcome :) . read  react-router docs for more cool options.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route
        path="/in-game/:data/:data2"
        render={(props) => <InGame {...props} />}
    />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

This implies that you can pass two arguments in the URL in-game as a get parameter. These 2 params can be parsed in InGame component as `this.props.match.params`

To call this URL anywhere, you can use (example)

```
<a href="/in-game/param1/param2">Click me</a>
```

or

```
history.push("/in-game/param1/param2")
```

Refer this post: [How to access 'this.props.match.params' along with other props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114416/how-to-access-this-props-match-params-along-with-other-props)

Comment: Edited my answer. Check once