# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I am writing a CRUD application in Java and React. I have an UpdateRecordComponent in react where I am using it to update a specific record. However everytime I click on the button to edit the record, it gives me the error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'params')".

The code is as below:

```
class UpdateContractorComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state={contractorId:'', contractorName:'', phoneNumber:'', email:''};
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        const contractorId = this.props.match.params.contractorId;
        if(contractorId > 0) {
            this.getContractorById(contractorId);
        }
    }
    getContractorById = (contractorId) => {
        ContractorService.getById(contractorId).then(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response);
                this.setState({
                    contractorId:response.data.contractorId,
                    contractorName:response.data.contractorName,
                    phoneNumber:response.data.phoneNumber,
                    email:response.data.email
                });
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Operation Failed");
            }
        );
    }
    onInputChange = e => {
        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]:e.target.value
        });
    }
    formHandle = e => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const contractor = {
            contractorName:this.state.contractorName,
            phoneNumber:this.state.phoneNumber,
            email:this.state.email
        };
        ContractorService.update(this.state.contractorId, contractor).then(
            (response) => {
                console.log(response);
                alert("Contractor Updated Successfully");
            }, (error) => {
                console.log(error);
                alert("Operation Failed");
            }
        );
    }
```

The error points to this line:

```
 const contractorId = this.props.match.params.contractorId;
```

I am using the latest versions of all the dependencies like react-router-dom, reactstrap, etc. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Are you sure you are using latest of all dependencies? `react-router-dom` v6 was a major update and doesn't support the same route props as in v4/5. Since you accepted the answer below which uses v5 then I'll assume you are not on the latest version. If you can, please update your question to include all relevant code and details. We should see how the route props are attempted to be passed to this `UpdateContractorComponent` component or how it's rendered in relation to `Route` component.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error says, the object "params" is `undefined`. The issue can be raised for multiple reasons (and I can't guess which they are since you didn't insert how your code pass information through the route).

The first thing to check is: are you overriding the `match` property?

When you spread `{...props}` your `match` prop overrides react-router's `match`. [Source: [Original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54114543/14106548)]

```
    <Route path='/champions/:id' render={(matchProps) =>
      <ChampionDetails
        {...matchProps}
        {...this.props}
        handleMatch={this.handleMatch}
      />
    }/>
```

If this is not your case I leave you a link that can help you in troubleshooting.

[How to access 'this.props.match.params' along with other props?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114416/how-to-access-this-props-match-params-along-with-other-props)

Comment: This is how I am routing the component from my App.js
```
        <Route path='/update-contractor/:contractorId' element={<UpdateContractorComponent/>}/>
```

Comment: Okay so I followed your code and it worked! Thank you.

Comment: The problem was how you were passing your component. You could also have used `component={UpdateContractorComponent}` instead of "render"