# Props is an empty object, so i cannot props.match.params.id

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

As said in title, my props is an empty object.
This is my component, in which i want to match a proper object in mapStateToProps.
The matching object exists, because when i pass and x.id === 1 , the object is being rendered.

```
const UserDetails = ({ episode, history }, props) => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  // const handleDelete = (id) => {
  //   if (window.confirm("Are you sure wanted to delete the episode ?")) {
  //     dispatch(deleteEpisode(id));
  //   }
  // };
  console.log("hej", props); // it prints empty object
  console.log(episode);
  return (
    <div>
      {episode ? (
        <div>
          <button onClick={() => history.push("/episodes")}>...back</button>
          <h1> Tytuł: {episode.title}</h1>
          <h3> Data wydania: {episode.release_date}</h3>
          <h3> Series: {episode.series} </h3>

          <img src={episode.img} alt="episode" />
          {/* <div>
            {episode.episode.characters.map((id) => {
              const properActor = users.find((el) => el.id == id);
              return <div>{`${properActor.name} `}</div>;
            })}
          </div> */}

          <button onClick={() => history.push(`/episode/edit/${episode.id}`)}>
            Edit
          </button>
          {/* <button onClick={() => handleDelete(episode.id)}>Delete</button> */}
          <div>
            <Link to={`/episodes/${episode.id}/addCharacter`}>
              <button type="button">Dodaj postać do: {episode.title}</button>
            </Link>
          </div>
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>Loading...</div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  return {
    episode: state.episodes.episodes
      ? state.episodes.episodes.find((x) => x.id === props.match.params.id)
      : null,
  };
};

export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, null)(UserDetails));
```

for anyone, who woudl like to see the whole project:

```
https://stackblitz.com/edit/node-fxxjko?file=db.json
```

hope it works,
to run the database u have to install `npm json-server` and run

**EDIT:**
If i do something like this:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, props) => {
  console.group("mapStateToProps");
  console.log(props); // Does props.match.params.id exist? What is it?
  console.log(state.episodes.episodes); // Is there an object in this array whose id matches the above?
  console.groupEnd();
  return {
    episode: state.episodes.episodes
      ? state.episodes.episodes.find(
          (x) => x.episodeId === props.match.params.episodeId
        )
      : null,
  };
};
```

i see the this  result:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/meKhF.jpg

Comment: This has already been answered: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54114416/how-to-access-this-props-match-params-along-with-other-props

Comment: @mmomtchev nah, this does not help me i have with router

Comment: x.episodeId === props.match.params.id if i do this it work for routers, but it render same object no matter what id, weird

Comment: I think this is the syntax you're looking for: `const UserDetails = ({ episode, history, ...props })`

Comment: There is no `props.match` without a router

Comment: @James, if i do something lime this, the props ja being printed to console, although the episode is still unfifined, as it couldnt be matched in mapStateToProps

Comment: I think the episode ID in `match.props.episodeID` is a string, whereas it's a number in your state object. Something like this should work `x.id === Number(props.match.params.id)`.

Answer (score 0):

You are not properly destructuring the rest of your props. Implement ellipsis to get the rest of the props back

It should be:

```js
const UserDetails = ({ episode, history, ...props}) => {
    //rest of your code
}
```

not:

```
const UserDetails = ({ episode, history }, props) => {
    //rest of your code
}
```